# Creating Sequence in Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I want to create a sequence of numbers in SQL Server that will have a minimum value and maximum value. I want to cycle if the number reaches the maximum limit. Can any body help me??

Comment: 1) Use a WHILE loop, and 2) you should take this over to http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: It all depends on how you are planning to use the sequence. All of the answers thus far make some assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a while loop. First, you need a Tally or Numbers table:

```
Create Table dbo.Numbers ( Value int not null Primary Key Clustered )
GO
With Nums As
    (
    Select Row_Number() Over( Order By S1.object_id ) As Num
    From sys.columns as s1
        cross join sys.columns as s2
    )
Insert dbo.Numbers( Value )
Select Num
From Nums
Where Num <= 100000
```

I only put a 100K of numbers in my table but you might need more. You need only populate this table once.Now you can create any sequence you desire. Like so:

```
Select Value
From dbo.Numbers
Where Value Between @Start And @End
```

Want an increment value?:

```
Select Value
From dbo.Numbers
Where Value % @Increment = 0
```

Comment: Agreed. Numbers / tally tables are very useful for so many features - it may appear overkill for this requirement but there are _so_ many other places where you'll find uses for them that I wouldn't bother with other solutions because you'll need this table sooner or later anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As of SQL Server 2012, sequences have been added and are supposedly faster than IDENTITY.

Quick example using `CYCLE` option as the question requests but most people probably will not use `CYCLE` because they'll use it for a synthetic primary key.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Schema.SequenceName
AS int
INCREMENT BY 1 
CYCLE;
```

Here's the SQL syntax [taken from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [schema_name . ] sequence_name  
    [ AS [ built_in_integer_type | user-defined_integer_type ] ]  
    [ START WITH <constant> ]  
    [ INCREMENT BY <constant> ]  
    [ { MINVALUE [ <constant> ] } | { NO MINVALUE } ]  
    [ { MAXVALUE [ <constant> ] } | { NO MAXVALUE } ]  
    [ CYCLE | { NO CYCLE } ]  
    [ { CACHE [ <constant> ] } | { NO CACHE } ]  
    [ ; ]
```

Here's how to do it in the GUI. This is the equivolent of the quick example above **without the `CYCLE` option** checked because most poeple won't use that:

1. In the *Object Explorer*, expand the *Programmability* folder
2. Under the *Programmability* folder, right click on the *Sequences*
   folder as shown below:

[image]

3. Underlined are the values that you would update to get the
   equivalent of the SQL statement above, however, I would consider
   changing these depending on your needs (see notes below).

[image]

Notes:

- The default Start value, Minimum value, and Maximum value were determined by the range of the data type which was an int in this case. [See here for more info on sequences and ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx).
- Pretty decent chance you'll want your sequence to start at 1 and you
  might want you minimum value as 1, too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that works in SQL 2000:

```
DECLARE @NumRows int;
SET @NumRows = 10000;
DECLARE @t table (RowNum int not null primary key);

-- Seed
INSERT @t VALUES(1)

WHILE @@ROWCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    INSERT @t
     SELECT     t.RowNum + x.MaxRowNum FROM @t t
     CROSS JOIN 
     (SELECT    MAX(RowNum) MaxRowNum FROM @t) x
     WHERE      t.RowNum <= @NumRows - x.MaxRowNum
END
```

Adapted from this: [Dr. Tom's Workshop: Generating Sequence Numbers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa175802%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: This loop will be increasingly slower than window function/CTE the more rows you need.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to create a sequence starting from 1

> CREATE SEQUENCE if not exists **sequence_name** START 1

It will work for you...