# Generating next sequence number in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

I have a need to generate a sequence number to be used as a primary key (in a legacy system)

I want to know if the following solution suffers from concurrency during race conditions.

```
CREATE TABLE SequenceGenerator
(
    Sequence INT
)

INSERT INTO SequenceGenerator SELECT 0
```

And here is the stored procedure that i will be calling whenever i need the next sequence number

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNextSequence
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @NextSequence INT
    UPDATE SequenceGenerator SET
    @NextSequence = Sequence,
    Sequence = Sequence + 1
    RETURN @NextSequence + 1
```

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server? 2012 has sequences, previous versions have `IDENTITY` columns. And it would be helpful if you explain why you want to write your own code for this anyway?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating Sequence in Sql Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1834733/creating-sequence-in-sql-server)

Comment: Here's how to do it in 2012: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39774566/3347858

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

Is there some reason you can't an identity field (ie: `identity(1,1)`) instead?

If you want to use the above code, you should certainly wrap it in a serializable transaction and handle any deadlock situations.

Comment: But my question was about "Is that UPDATE statement atomic?.. If so.. then it is by default in an implicit transaction. If that is true.. then why wrap in a transaction? And where can it deadlock?"
Sorry.. If my original question was not clear.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why do you not use **Identity** column ?

```
IDENTITY [ (seed ,increment) ]
```

[IDENTITY (Property)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933196%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Eg.

```
CREATE TABLE SequenceGenerator
(
    Sequence INT IDENTITY(1,1)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick, you wont run into concurrency problems.

```
CREATE TABLE SequenceGenerator(Sequence INT)
GO
INSERT INTO SequenceGenerator SELECT 0
GO

DECLARE @NextSequence INT

UPDATE SequenceGenerator 
SET @NextSequence = Sequence = Sequence + 1
```

@NextSequence will have incremented value

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but I've had the following working in SQL Server 2008 R2 for years, and it's never let me down:

I have a table with a 'Name' and 'LastValue' column:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ReserveSequence]
@Name varchar(100),
@Count int,
@FirstValue bigint OUTPUT
AS 
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Results TABLE ([LastValue] bigint)

UPDATE [Sequences]
SET [LastValue] = [LastValue] + @Count
OUTPUT INSERTED.LastValue INTO @Results
WHERE [Name] = @Name;

SELECT TOP 1 @FirstValue = [LastValue] + 1 FROM @Results;
RETURN 0;
END
```

That said, I'd be using SEQUENCE objects if you're targetting 2012 or later.