# MVC3: Razor Engine: Random generation of 3 digit unique numeric string

Tags: .net

I want to generate 3 digit random numeric string on a click event of button 'NextAvailable' in MVC3 Razor c#.net. The numeric string should be non repeated and before generation of numeric string I need to check in SQL 2008 database, that whether the string is present or not. If present, then generate a new numeric string.
I am very much new to MVC-3. Is there any help for View and Controller code? Or any logic that how should i achieve this functionality? It would be a great help.

Comment: Do you need help on the *logic* side or on the *web* side? These are very different situations.

Answer (score 0):

3 unique digits means there can only be 999 items in your database, that may or may not be a problem.  also, if there are only 999 entries available, why do they need to be random?

Regardless, identifying and selecting the next item in a sequence is a problem that can be solved in your database with a stored procedure.  Your controller would execute the stored procedure via a method on one of your repository objects.

It looks like this functionality is [built into Sql Server 2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878370.aspx), otherwise, you can build your own - here is an explanation on how to do that: [Generating next sequence number in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13586527/generating-next-sequence-number-in-sql-server)